# using R to web scrape data from javascripted download button

Tags: r, web-scraping, v8, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to web scrape the csv generated by clicking the 'CSV' button on this [site](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/fromshowcolumns.asp?Travel=NIxSTxTIxSUx&FromSeries=1&ToSeries=50&DAT=RNG&FD=1&FM=Jan&FY=2009&TD=30&TM=Mar&TY=2020&FNY=&CSVF=TT&html.x=91&html.y=29&C=IIN&Filter=N#) (located below the left side of the graph). The problem is that the CSV is generated from Javascript that parses the embedded table (below middle of graph). I am aware I could just scrape the embedded table . I do not want to do this.

I want a solution that uses R to download a csv from the 'CSV' button. My attempt so far uses the r packages "rvest" and "V8". I'm just confused on what I do as I can't find good examples of the V8  package being used on javascript download buttons. Here's what I got so far.

I'm confused on the line ct <- v8() onwards... How do i apply the V8 package in the context of the javascript in the source code of the above URL?

```
library(rvest)
library(V8)

URL <- https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/fromshowcolumns.asp?Travel=NIxSTxTIxSUx&FromSeries=1&ToSeries=50&DAT=RNG&FD=1&FM=Jan&FY=2009&TD=30&TM=Mar&TY=2020&FNY=&CSVF=TT&html.x=91&html.y=29&C=IIN&Filter=N#

raw_html <- GET(URL) %>% 
     content() %>% 
     rvest::html_nodes("script") %>% 
     html_text() 

 ct <- v8() 

   read_html(ct$eval(gsub('document.ready','',raw_html))) %>% 

   html_text()
```

For Context, the javascript for the buttons are as below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD MMM YY' );

    $('#stats-table').DataTable( {
    paging: false,
    "info":     false,
    "order": [ 0, 'desc' ],
    fixedHeader: {
    header: true
    },
     dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'
        ]
    } );

} );
</script>
```

Comment: using v8 directly is very difficult. Can you use node?

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment. I can potentially use any CRAN packages but i'm afraid I can only use R.

Are you aware of a solution using R?

Thanks

Comment: "I can only use R" v8 is not R, its C++

Comment: It's also a package in R. I was trying to refer to the V8 R package. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear earlier. I've edited the question to try and reflect this better.

Answer (score 0):

A `RSelenium` solution,

```
library(RSelenium)
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))

remDr <- driver[["client"]]
# Naigate to website
remDr$navigate("https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/database/fromshowcolumns.asp?Travel=NIxSTxTIxSUx&FromSeries=1&ToSeries=50&DAT=RNG&FD=1&FM=Jan&FY=2009&TD=30&TM=Mar&TY=2020&FNY=&CSVF=TT&html.x=91&html.y=29&C=IIN&Filter=N#")
#Download the CSV file
button_element <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="stats-table_wrapper"]/div[1]/a[2]')
button_element$clickElement()
```